# bootstrap datepicker issue in Angular 2 project?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have angular2-cli project.

I am trying to add bootstrap-datepicker in Angular Component.

Here is my code snippet.

```
angular-cli.json
...
"style": ["../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css",...]
"scripts": ["../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js",...]
XXX.component.ts
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
  $("#date").datepicker({autoclose:true});
}
```

But I have got some error below with position problem.

[image]

So I can't use autoclose functionality.

Here is image regarding position issue.

[image]

Datepicker shows up at top of input box.

I tried to change CSS but is not working well.

Help me with advice!!!

Comment: Do you have [the types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootstrap-datepicker) for bootstrap-datepicker installed?  Typescript doesn't know about the options with just loading the minified file.

Comment: Thank you very much @JSess.
I fixed it by following your advice.Can you help me about position issue?

Comment: What do your markup look like for the datepicker component?  Could you edit your answer to show that information?  Ensure you have the appropriate classes and attributes applied per their documentation.  Any other styles for the parent (if you're overriding the position, for example) may affect the position as well.